# Problema ao passar parâmetro no form | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma aplicação para gerenciamento de projetos, e que cada projeto possuem suas tarefas. Essas tarefas podem ser excluídas ou concluídas.

Cada task é exibida através de um foreach, que está dentro de uma view, sendo exibida dentro de um card, e dentro deste card, possui dois botões, um para cada ação.

Para carregar esta página, ela é chamada através de um controller (ProjectController) e ao clicar nos botões, chamo um modal para confirmar tal conclusão ou exclusão e ao confirmar, chamo o controller (TaskController).

No entanto, quando faço qualquer uma das ações, obtenho o mesmo erro: `Undefined variable: task_id (View: C:\Users\User\project-manager\resources\views\modals\modals.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\User\project-manager\resources\views\modals\modals.blade.php)`

ProjectController (exibe a página com as tarefas):

```
public function show($id)
{
    $task = Task::all()
        ->where('project_id', '=', $id);

    $task_id = Task::all()
        ->where('project_id', '=', $id)
        ->first();

    $task_count = count($task);
    $t = $task->where('final_date', '!=', null);
    $task_done = count($t);
    $task_not_done = $task_count - $task_done;
    return view('project.edit', ['project' => Project::findOrFail($id)])
        ->with('task', $task)
        ->with('task_count', $task_count)
        ->with('task_done', $task_done)
        ->with('task_not_done', $task_not_done)
        ->with('task_id', $task_id);
}
```

Modal para conclusão/exclusão das tasks:

```
<!-- Modal to check a task -->
<div class="modal fade" id="check" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Atenção!</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('tasks_update', $task_id->id) }}" method="PUT">
                    <p>
                        Você deseja concluir esta tarefa?
                    </p>
                    @csrf
                    <input name="code" id="code" type="hidden" value="1">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Concluir</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route: `Route::put('tasks/{id}', 'TaskController@update')->name('tasks_update');`

TaskController (realiza update):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if($request->input('code') == 1){
        DB::table('tasks')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->update(['check' => 1]);
        return view()->route('projects.show');
    }

    if($request->input('code') == 2) {
        DB::table('tasks')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->update(['deleted_at' => now()]);
        return view()->route('projects.show');
    }
}
```

Obs.: estou usando o route resourcer do Laravel;
já tentei deixar o modal na mesma página onde estão sendo exibido os cards das tarefas;
observei também que ao clicar no botão, não consigo nem chegar no controller;

Comment: O seu código tem problemas, você está utilizando errado o `Eloquent` e os valores podem estar enviando informações erradas para as `Views`. Só uma constatação: se você precisa filtrar o model `Task` faça antes de chamar o comando do banco, se não você traz todo conteúdo das tabelas para depois filtrar e isso é um problema.

Comment: Você poderia dizer onde está o erro?

Comment: `$task = Task::all()->where('project_id', '=', $id);` aqui por exemplo

Comment: estou perguntando, pois não faço a mínima ideia de como faço isso, mas como eu filtro os itens sem mesmo fazer a consulta no banco?

Comment: deveria ser `$task = Task::where('project_id', '=', $id);` e se precisar carregar `$task = Task::where('project_id', '=', $id)->get();`

Comment: legal, fiz assim, o resultado foi o mesmo. Isso é uma boa prática? Ou é devido na primeira vez eu ter carregado tudo e depois feito os filtros? Perdemos em performance?

Comment: o resultado é o mesmo, mas, a otimização no retorno é tamanha, então você faz o filtro direto na SQL e não em uma classe que carrega toda a tabela !!! essa é a diferença desempenho...